# How to add own custom template in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

Hi i try to add own custom template in magneto but i am unable to do this i use the following step as given below
    first i create a own directory in app/code/local

```
   - FirstNameSpace
    - FirstWeb
      -controllers
       -IndexController.php
```

and the code of IndexController.php as

```
<?php
class FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

    }
    public function testAction()
    {
        echo "test action";
    }
}
```

and the magneto app/etc/modules/FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb.xml

code as

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
       <FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And in the app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/firstweb.xml
  code like this

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <firstweb_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="firstweb/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </firstweb_index_index>
</layout>
```

and in the template/firstweb/form.phtml like

Hi how are u ! this is the first example

and the config.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <firstweb>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb</module>
                    <frontName>firstweb</frontName>
                </args>
            </firstweb>
        </routers>
       <!-- This node contains module layout configuration -->

 <layout>
            <updates>
                <contact>
                    <file>firstweb.xml</file>
                </contact>
            </updates>
        </layout>

    </frontend>
</config>


 Now if i hit the page :http://localhost/magento/index.php/firstweb/index
```

i did not get any response

plz help me so i can able to load the layout in magneto

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong.

Set the page template:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <firstweb_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="firstweb/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </firstweb_index_index>
</layout>
```

Render your layout:

```
<?php
class FirstNameSpace_FirstWeb_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

    }
    public function testAction()
    {
        echo "test action";
    }
}
```

Also, your config is wrong, should be firstweb instead of contact. Contact is being used by the core module Contacts:

```
         <updates>
            <firstweb>
                <file>firstweb.xml</file>
            </firstweb>
        </updates>
```

Try it out and if still doesn't work, keep trying until you get it all right.

Comment: it is still not working. and i am trying it lot of time . can u provide me complete example

Comment: come on @kavita, "it is still not working" is not helpful at all. Consider hiring a professional to do that work for you.